# Merge / concatenate multiple mp4 files without ffmpeg

Tags: php, mp4

I do not know if it is even possible. I have 6 mp4 videos and I want to combine them in one single mp4 file using PHP. The problem is I do not have ffmpeg on the server where I need to do this, and it is not possible for me to install it since it is not my own server. I wondered if there were maybe some other ways or possibilities to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, It is possible with php, As php does not provide any extensive Audio/Video manipulation lib in core. So you will need some extra packages like ffmpeg, lame etc.

Comment: i'm also looking into this, from what i understand, if you can adjust the headers of the mp4 file properly, you can simply remove headers, then concatenate the files and create one header for the big file